# Scroll to div -sticky nav height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a sticky navigation on my website. When somebody clicks on one of the navigation items it scrolls down to the relevant part of the site but currently the sticky nav is overlapping the div so it looks like it hasn't scrolled to the top of the div.

The code for the scroll looks like this:

```
$(".nav-kontakt").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#kontakt").offset().top - $("#nav").outerHeight(true)
    },
    'slow');
  });
});
```

Nav:

```
<div class="nav-row">
  <ul class="nav-item">
    <li class="nav-leistungen">Leistungen</li>
    <li class="nav-philosophie">Philosophie</li>
    <li class="nav-kontakt" id="last">Kontakt</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Scrolling to:

```
<div class="container" id="kontakt">
  <div class="heading-line">
    <span>Kontakt</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you can see I've tried to scroll - the height of #nav, but this doesn't seem to work and it still overlaps the .nav-kontakt div.

Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong or a different apporach?

Comment: What does your markup look like? Are you using anchors or IDs? And does your outerHeight return a correct value?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you create a demo to help you, but first try this

```
var fix = 0; // type integer
var nav = $(".nav-row").outerHeight(true);

$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+selector).offset().top - nav - fix
}, 'slow');
```

Remember that the scroll will not move more than the size of the page.

Look at this example (https://jsfiddle.net/idkc/zchzb2b8/6/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.nav-item li").click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var fix = 0;
    var nav = $(".nav-row").outerHeight(true);
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#" + selector).offset().top - nav - fix
    }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-row {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
}

.contents {
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-row">
  <ul class="nav-item">
    <li class="nav-leistungen" data-id="content1">Leistungen</li>
    <li class="nav-philosophie" data-id="content2">Philosophie</li>
    <li class="nav-kontakt" data-id="content3">Kontakt</li>
    <li class="nav-xxxx" data-id="content4">pppppppppppppp</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="contents">
  <div class="container" id="content1">
    <div class="heading-line">
      <span>content 1</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nulla corporis odio totam magni ea consequatur. Vel quidem, doloremque quia vero reprehenderit dolorum qui atque, magni itaque, esse deserunt. Deserunt.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="content2">
    <div class="heading-line">
      <span>content 2</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nulla corporis odio totam magni ea consequatur. Vel quidem, doloremque quia vero reprehenderit dolorum qui atque, magni itaque, esse deserunt. Deserunt.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="content3">
    <div class="heading-line">
      <span>content 3</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nulla corporis odio totam magni ea consequatur. Vel quidem, doloremque quia vero reprehenderit dolorum qui atque, magni itaque, esse deserunt. Deserunt.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="content4">
    <div class="heading-line">
      <span>content 4</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa nulla corporis odio totam magni ea consequatur. Vel quidem, doloremque quia vero reprehenderit dolorum qui atque, magni itaque, esse deserunt. Deserunt.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```